# on click to hide div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show and hide some `div` on click and I managed to achieve part of it (it shows divs and hide them when I click on corresponding buttons).

However, I don't know how to close all the already opened divs when I click on other buttons.
For example if I click on "add" button and it opens the corresponding `div`, and when I click on "edit" I want to open "edit" div and close "add" div.

My relevant HTML

```
<div id="controls">
    <input type="button" class="addBtn" value="Add" id="add"/>
    <input type="button" class="editBtn" value="Edit"  id="edit"/>
    <input type="button" class="viewBtn" value="View" id="view"/>
    <input type="button" class="deleteBtn" value="Delete" id="delete"/>
</div>
<div id="test1">test 1</div>
<div id="test2">test 2</div>
<div id="test3">test 3</div>
```

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add").click(function(){
        $("#test1").slideToggle("fast");
    });
    $("#edit").click(function(){
        $("#test2").slideToggle("fast");
    });
    $("#view").click(function(){
        $("#test3").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Thanks for suggestions and tips.

Comment: You haven't closed your `head` tag.

Comment: there are so many possible solution to this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i guess this is the simplest thing you can do.. hope this helps you..

```
<div id="controls">
<input type="button" class="addBtn" value="Add" id="add"/>
<input type="button" class="editBtn" value="Edit"  id="edit"/>
<input type="button" class="viewBtn" value="View" id="view"/>
<input type="button" class="deleteBtn" value="Delete" id="delete"/>
</div>
<div id="test1">test 1</div>
<div id="test2">test 2</div>
<div id="test3">test 3</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alaskaz1864/VtLzB/1/

Comment: Thanks, that was the thing that I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

[replace your jquery code with the following code](http://jsfiddle.net/EGgM9/)

```
  $(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("#add").click(function(){
         $("#test1").show();
        $("#test2,#test3").hide();
    });
    $("#edit").click(function(){
    $("#test2").slideToggle("fast");
        $("#test1,#test3").hide();
    });
    $("#view").click(function(){
    $("#test3").slideToggle("fast");
        $("#test1, #test2").hide();
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `attribute starts with selector` to grab the similar elements, hide it after grabbing it then after that do your normal process,

```
$("#add").click(function(){
 $('div[id^=test]').hide();
 $("#test1").slideToggle("fast");
});

$("#edit").click(function(){
 $('div[id^=test]').hide();
 $("#test2").slideToggle("fast");
});

$("#view").click(function(){
 $('div[id^=test]').hide();
 $("#test3").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rK7rc/)

---

Even simpler,

```
$('[type=button]:not(#delete)').click(function(){
 $('div[id^=test]').hide().eq($(this).index()).slideToggle("fast");
});
```

## Special Note:

This code does not expect us to change the DOM structure by adding/**hardcoding** data-attribute.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rK7rc/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a common class to those elements, to close them all before opening the required one. You can also put `data` attributes on the buttons to DRY up your code. Try this:

```
<div id="controls">
    <input type="button" class="addBtn" data-rel="#test1" value="Add" id="add" />
    <input type="button" class="editBtn" data-rel="#test2" value="Edit" id="edit" />
    <input type="button" class="viewBtn" data-rel="#test3" value="View" id="view" />
    <input type="button" class="deleteBtn" value="Delete" id="delete" />
</div>
<div id="test1" class="content">test 1</div>
<div id="test2" class="content">test 2</div>
<div id="test3" class="content">test 3</div>
```

```js
$('#controls input').click(function() {
    $('.content').slideUp('fast');
    $($(this).data('rel')).slideDown('fast');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GCp73/)

Comment: +1 for using data hooks instead of individual functions for each button.

Comment: you could do `$(rel).slideDown('fast').siblings('.content').slideUp('fast');` too ;)

Comment: Thank you, it was helpful and it helped me with more then than one problem. Also, I learn few things.

Answer (score 1):

your jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#add").click(function(){
    $("div").not("#test1,#controls").hide();
$("#test1").slideToggle("fast");

});
$("#edit").click(function(){
    $("div").not("#test2,#controls").hide();
$("#test2").slideToggle("fast");

});
$("#view").click(function(){
  $("div").not("#test3,#controls").hide();
$("#test3").slideToggle("fast");

});
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/zqHaZ/)